# Jenkins + Ant and parallel scp/sshexec

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ant

Have Jenkins build that use Ant to do heavy lifting.

First it fetch code, tar it, scp, sshexec to extract it, sshexec it again to install it.

There are 2 production servers right now. So I used `for` from *ant-contrib* to run scp/sshexec in parallel. For param is used to set property which is then used in scp/sshexec - to avoid issues with @ vs $ notations.
However that's not working as expected.

I either get:

- connection reset
- ssh-agaent not present (from production server sshd logs)
- Windows sockets not found
- scp doulbe write server to which it's connecting (but that transfer succeds)

Build always fail at second scp/sshexec, which is strange since second connection should happen to **different** server.

**Questions:**
What am I doing wrong?
Or alternatively how to write that ant script differently, while still achieving parallelism?

Answer (score 0):

This is root cause:
**For param is used to set property which is then used in scp/sshexec - to avoid issues with @ vs $ notations.**

Ant properties are **IMMUTABLE**, so if set at first itteration to X, it would stay X for all the iterations of that loop!

So I either had to stick to serial execution and unsetting each parameter at the end of `sequential` or use `@` syntax and `parallel` loop if possible. `sshexec` did accept `@`syntax.